# Dart Abstraction & Polymorphism conundrum

Tags: oop, dart, inheritance, polymorphism, abstraction

Please find the below dart snippet

```
class A {
  String m1_a() {
    return "A -> m1_a()";
  }
}

abstract class B extends A {
  @override
  String m1_a();
}

class C extends B {}

void main() {
  B c_b = C();

  print(c_b.m1_a()); //"A -> m1_a()"
}
```

Q. Why C is not enforce to override the abstract method *m1_a()* define by **class B** ?

> B is declared as Abstract class so ideally m1_a() is also abstract method for child C !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dart class declarations introduce both a *class* (which can be extended and instantiated) and an *interface* (which can be implemented).
Unlike other similar languages, Dart doesn't have a separate `interface` declaration, you can extract an interface from any class.
A non-abstract class must always have an implementation for its own interface.

A concrete method in a class declaration, like `int foo() => 42;`, introduces both a method signature to the declared interface and an implementation to the declared class, and since they match up, the class does indeed implement the interface.

An abstract method, like `int foo();`, only adds a method to the interface, it does not affect the class. If the class is abstract, and has no implementation of `foo`, then that's perfectly fine.

In this example, the `B` class declaration declares `String m1_a();` which adds  an interface signature for the interface of `B`. That has absolutely no effect since it also inherits the same signature from the interface of `A`.
Further, the `B` class inherits an implementation of `m1_a` from the class `A`, so it successfully implements its interface, and all is well.

TL;DR: The abstract method has no implementation, and has no effect on implementations, only on interfaces, so it doesn't shadow the inherited concrete method implementation from `A`.

The fact that an abstract method doesn't shadow an inherited implementation, can be used to update documentation in a subclass without affecting the implementation. Example:

```dart
class A {
  /// Does something using A.
  int foo() => something + _private();

  int _private() => _somethingSpecial();
}
class B {
  /// Does something using B.
  int foo();

  int _private() => _somethingSpecialForB();
}
```

Here you change the behavior of `foo` in `B` because you change how the private function it depends on works, but you don't change the shared code in `A.foo`. You can still update the documentation of `B.foo` to say how it differs.

Comment: Gotcha !

All in all, m1_a() is no longer abstract method in B class despite it appears on first look (via syntax)